# 2 Objects of same type mapping to MySQL DB problem

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, database-design

```
public class Purchase {
    public Address to { get; set; }
    public Address from { get; set; }

}
public class Address {
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I have 1 Purchase with 2 Address. How this should be on the Database (mySql) including foreign keys to be used on Entity Framework.

I have the problem that entity understands (based on fk) that Navigability in Address is 1 to many (*) and I don't have a list of Address on Purchase, i have defined 2.

Thanks,
Bart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure relationships of the tables.Build your model like this,

```
 public class PurchaseConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Purchase >
{
      public PurchaseConfiguration()
      {

           HasRequired(p=>p.to ).WithOptionalDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
           HasRequired(p => p.from ).WithOptionalDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
      }

 }
```

and your db context you can add the configurations like this,

```
public class yourDbContext:DbContext
{
        public DbSet<Purchase> Purchases{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses{ get; set; }
        //other db sets here..

       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
          modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PurchaseConfiguration ());
          // you can add configurations for other tables 
         }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatelly, I'm new into entity. It would be great if i understand what that does, how it does and where should i use that. Can you please explain a little more?

Comment: See I have edited the answer. I think you need to look at a tutorial like this at first.http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application